# Remove ISO9660 Extension

Tags: mac, usb, mp3, iso-image, u3

I have an ISO9660 thing on my MP3 player and I can't seem to get it to be removed. Do you guys have any idea?

Comment: Seems to be the U3 Launchpad.

Answer (score 2):

If it is what I think it is, the answer is no.

ISO 9660 is basically CDFS (CD-Rom File System). Many devices have a hardware coded / built in partition that will be recognised by computers as a CD-Rom drive and contain nothing but drivers for the device.

The good news is that usually this partition does not come out of any of the usable space as it is usually hard coded into the firmware.

The bad news is, you can't usually touch or modify it.